# How to parse xml having multiple child and in that child there is data?

Tags: android, xml, parsing, xml-parsing

- Here is my xml,

  ```
  <root>
    <child>
        <Lunchmenu>
             <id>2</id>
             <lunch_date>2013-10-24</lunch_date>
             <break_name>Lunch</break_name>
             <class_id/>
             <school_id>1</school_id>
             <batch_id/>
       </Lunchmenu>
       <Eatable>
             <id>2</id>
             <eatable_name>Apples</eatable_name>
       </Eatable>
   </child>
    <child>
        <Lunchmenu>
             <id>2</id>
             <lunch_date>2013-10-24</lunch_date>
             <break_name>Lunch</break_name>
             <class_id/>
             <school_id>1</school_id>
             <batch_id/>
       </Lunchmenu>
       <Eatable>
             <id>3</id>
             <eatable_name>Orange</eatable_name>
       </Eatable>
  </child>
  ```
- I need to know that, is there any way to parse above xml's child as there are again two separate tags like Lunchmenu and eatable.
- I am using sax parser to parse this xml.
- I know how to parse single child tag having data and again its iteration, but here I am confused how to do it?
- please suggest any solution if anyone knows How to parse it??
- thank you
- and my parser class is : 
  SchoolParser.java

public class SchoolParser extends DefaultHandler {

```
private List<School> schoolListData ;
private boolean isSuccess;
private School school;
StringBuilder tempData;

@Override
public void startDocument() throws SAXException {

    super.startDocument();
    Log.e("StudentListParser","startDocument");
    schoolListData = new ArrayList<School>();
}

public List<School> getSchoolListData(){
    return schoolListData;
}

@Override
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
        org.xml.sax.Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {

    super.startElement(uri, localName, qName, attributes);

    if (localName.equals("School")) {
        school = new School();
        Log.e("SchoolParser", "-----START----");
    } 
    tempData = new StringBuilder();

}

@Override
public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
        throws SAXException {
    super.characters(ch, start, length);
    tempData.append(new String(ch, start, length));
}

@Override
public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
        throws SAXException {
    super.endElement(uri, localName, qName);
    if(localName.equals("School")){
        schoolListData.add(school);
        Log.d("localName",localName);

    }
    else if (localName.equals("id")) {
        Log.e("id", localName);

        school.id = Integer.parseInt(tempData.toString());

    } else if (localName.equals("school_name")) {
        school.schoolName = tempData.toString();
        Log.e("name", localName);

    } else if (localName.equals("logo")) {
        school.logo = tempData.toString().getBytes();
        Log.e("logo", localName);

    }else if (localName.equals("phone")) {
        school.phn_no = tempData.toString();
        Log.e("phn no", localName);

    } 
    else if (localName.equals("School")) {
        Log.e("SchoolParser", "----END---");
    }
    //          int size = buffer.length(); 
    //          buffer.delete(0, size);
    //          Log.i("buffer is empty", ""+buffer.toString());
}

@Override
public void endDocument() throws SAXException {
    super.endDocument();
    isSuccess = false;
    Log.e("StudentListParser", "endDocument");
}
```

}

Comment: Can you suggest me then..

Comment: I have added parser class for the xml having only one child tag.. I need to know that how to create code for above queried xml.. please suggest..

Comment: Sir, I dont know how to create and use as serializable.. I am doing this first time.. please suggest or post code .. please..

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use serialize logic to parse xml to direct java class object.

You can use below class..

```
package com.lib.android.util;

import java.io.InputStream;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.simpleframework.xml.Serializer;
import org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister;
import com.lib.android.util.logger.PLogger;

public class XmlParser
{
    private static Logger log = new PLogger(XmlParser.class).getLogger();

    public static Object Parse(Class<? extends Object> parseInto, InputStream is)
    {
        Serializer serializer = new Persister();
        try
        {
            Object obj = serializer.read(parseInto, is);
            return obj;
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            log.error(e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Hope it will help you..

Comment: to use this you need to make model class according to the xml file.. but it will be better way to code in java.